# Xampp vs. Lamp Localhost Install

Tags: server, lamp, xampp, localhost

I originally installed Xampp for my localhost needs.  I uninstalled it and installed LAMP.  I have been trying to work on my WordPress business site since then but keep running into problem I can't figure out.  I try to go into page (which I now see is still labeled as a post if that matters) and proceed ahead with needed changes.  Then when I try to preview or bring up the page for further review, it appears that it's coming up as if in Xampp, not LAMP as it shows the Xampp icon in the tab.  BUT it doesn't open up at all.  I don't know what to do to fix this or how to go about being able to continue to work on my work site to the point where I can upload it onto my hosting site.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.  :)

Comment: When you say you installed LAMP, do you mean a proper LAMP Stack (Apache, mysql and PHP)? How did you install it? Can you also add logs and any applicable errors?

Comment: Images will help, is this on a local machine or VPS?

Comment: Thanks ThatGuy for your response.  I first used XAMPP but couldn't get the site itself to come back up once I shut down and rebooted.  Not really new at this but still very unsure of stuff I

Comment: Thanks for answering.  LAST install this time was using "sudo apt-get install lamp-server^".  Hope that is what you mean by "proper LAMP Stack".  Please advise.

Comment: thanks George, for writing back.  I'd be glad to give you images but unfortunately I worked on this close to 24 hours ago and didn't approach you til I was soooooo frustrated that I felt I needed your additional help.

Comment: I think it's installed ok.  I just can't get the "preview/view page" after correcting it to come up.  I can view the website but it is not taking any of the corrections or updates.  Only option I have is to work on the site while on my hosting site, online, and I'm sure the hosting site won't like that.  Is there any Linux program out there that can set up localhost with WordPress for me?  And, is there an easy way to have access to multiple websites through WordPress via localhost?

Comment: As I look through the instructions found at "tutweaks.com", I have to tell you that I did not get the "Test Apache" page to come up as in their example.  Mine was the default page all about Apache, not the "it works" page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove them both and install LAMP with `tasksel`:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Check the LAMP server and click "ok".

After that install phpmyadmin and copy-paste your WordPress directory into 
`/var/www/html`
folder and run it.

Comment: Far too much code. `sudo apt install lamp-server^` does the same (the ^ points it to the task from tasksel).